# How to use Conditional GANs for Categorical Music Generation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I have got a graduation project which is AI Music Generator. But I will generate the music based on the mood it gives to the people. For example if I choose to generate a happy type music, then I will generate a happy type music. Or If I want to choose sad or gloomy or peaceful, I want to generate that type of music respectively. I already Trained my Model using LSTM without any categorization. I use MIDI files for my dataset and I label them as Happy, Sad, Peaceful and Gloomy respectively. I use Music21 library for preprocessing the midi files. But I don't know how to use CGANs for my purpose since I am not that experienced on Machine Learning so I need a help.
Here is the code How I parsed the MIDI files and created the notes.

```
def get_notes():
    notes = []
    happy = []
    sad = []
    peaceful = []
    gloomy = []

    for file in songs:
        print(file)

        # converting .mid file to stream object
        midi = converter.parse(file)
        notes_to_parse = []
        try:
            # Given a single stream, partition into a part for each unique instrument
            parts = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)
        except:
            pass
        if parts:  # if parts has instrument parts
            notes_to_parse = parts.parts[0].recurse()
        else:
            notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes

        for element in notes_to_parse:
            if isinstance(element, note.Note):
                # if element is a note, extract pitch
                notes.append(str(element.pitch))
            elif (isinstance(element, chord.Chord)):
                # if element is a chord, append the normal form of the
                # chord (a list of integers) to the list of notes.
                notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))

        if file.split("_")[-1].split(".")[-2] == "happy":
            with open('data/happy', 'wb') as filepath:
                pickle.dump(notes, filepath)

        elif file.split("_")[-1].split(".")[-2] == "sad":
            with open('data/sad', 'wb') as filepath:
                pickle.dump(notes, filepath)

        if file.split("_")[-1].split(".")[-2] == "peaceful":
            with open('data/peaceful', 'wb') as filepath:
                pickle.dump(notes, filepath)
        
        if file.split("_")[-1].split(".")[-2] == "gloomy":
            with open('data/gloomy', 'wb') as filepath:
                pickle.dump(notes, filepath)
```

In that Code I extracted all the MIDI files according to their labels and created their note files respectively. The file names are also happy, sad, peaceful, gloomy. I created the files using pickle.dump().

Here is How I load the dataset again from the files that I created earlier.

```
happy = pickle.load(open('data/happy', 'rb'))
sad = pickle.load(open('data/sad', 'rb'))
peaceful = pickle.load(open('data/peaceful', 'rb'))
gloomy = pickle.load(open('data/gloomy', 'rb'))

print("Data loaded")

return happy, sad, peaceful, gloomy
```

After this Operation we got our features extracted from our MIDI files. But They are not in Machine Learnable format yet. So we call this function to end the preprocessing and suitable to use it with LSTM Network.

```
def prepare_sequences(notes, n_vocab):
    sequence_length = 100

    # Extract the unique pitches in the list of notes.
    pitchnames = sorted(set(item for item in notes))

    # Create a dictionary to map pitches to integers
    note_to_int = dict((note, number) for number, note in enumerate(pitchnames))

    network_input = []
    network_output = []

    # create input sequences and the corresponding outputs
    for i in range(0, len(notes) - sequence_length, 1):
        sequence_in = notes[i: i + sequence_length]
        sequence_out = notes[i + sequence_length]
        network_input.append([note_to_int[char] for char in sequence_in])
        network_output.append(note_to_int[sequence_out])

    n_patterns = len(network_input)

    # reshape the input into a format comatible with LSTM layers
    network_input = np.reshape(network_input, (n_patterns, sequence_length, 1))

    # normalize input
    network_input = network_input / float(n_vocab)

    # one hot encode the output vectors
    network_output = np_utils.to_categorical(network_output)

    return (network_input, network_output)
```

Now I couldn't quite understand all of the procedures but I think It literally converts the notes to integers so this function makes the data trainable for the specific model. Also this code is from the LSTM code that uses only one note file which is list of notes. I need to modify this method for my happy, sad, peaceful and gloomy datasets and make it available for the CGAN model. I don't know what to do in that case. How can I use the labels? What operations should use? Anyway. If you help me I would be very happy.

Comment: Does your work really need to be based on cGANs? GANs are generally difficult to train and I'm not sure how good are the results they could provide to your case. I would go for a different strategy: encoding musical notes as embeddings (similar to what is done for text), then training a CNN to find the next note given a context of notes. A new music would be generated by continously predicting the next note. Each music style(based on mood, in your case) would be the result of a different CNN. This technique is based on NLP and I believe to provide far better results than GANs to your problem.

Comment: @GOliveira Maybe. But It is already decided that to use CGAN for my purpose in the beginning. If I would have done it in a different way it would be fail for me unfortunately.